# how to set mac desktop background as working terminal

Tags: macos, mac, terminal

I would like to set my background to a working Terminal window even when I minimize all applications. I would like to be able to write commands on desktop but I don't know if it is even possible.

I have done some Google searching but I could not find any clues. If this is possible, could you explain the process of setting it up?

I am using Mac OS X 10.7.5

Answer (score 1):

You might to want to checkout this tool called [GeekTool](http://projects.tynsoe.org/en/geektool/) as their site states:

> GeekTool is an application for Mac OS 10.6+. It lets you display various kinds of information on your desktop via 3 default plug-ins

Answer (score 1):

[iTerm2](http://www.iterm2.com/#/section/home) in fullscreen does what you want. At least it does for me when I reboot when it launches on boot.

In iTerm2 you can define different window styles. I have only one defined (fullscreen, toggled with a key combination <kbd>⌥ Opt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>). If you don't set a toggle you get a non-standard fullscreen window (chrome-less fullscreen). If you manage to get it under all other windows you get what you want.

Comment: But in OSX full screen mode, you can't have other windows on top of it... unless I'm missing something

Comment: iTerm2 has a built-in full-screen mode that's not native to OS X (it just covers all other windows). You can get windows on top of it but I found it far more useful to just have it under the key combination mentioned.

Dig in iTerms settings to set it up.

As an aside, since I answered this question I moved back to Linux so possibly stuff changed. Either ways I'm happy as long as I can keep my terminals full-screen and under a key combination (rocking Guake now).